# table for even connections

Tags: database

```
id | element
----------
 1 | Milk
 2 | Bread
 3 | Butter
```

Milk and Butter have "connection". And Bread and Butter have "connection".
These are *even* connection, not parent-child.

How can i display them?

```
id1 | id2
----------
 1  |  3
 2  |  3
```

yes, but

```
id1 | id2
----------
 3  |  1
 3  |  2
```

also right, there are no first and second.

How can this be done?

Comment: what is an "even" connection do you mean a 1 to 1 relationship?

Comment: it is "not parent-child" connection. Just usual connection: one is somehow connected with second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To demonstrate, I'm going to invent the scenario that you're talking about recipes and ingredients.  Perhaps you're not. Either way, you want to make a 'set' which contains any number of the 'items' in a many-to-many relationship.

Make a table called a "RECIPE" or similar, which looks like this:

- RECIPE_ID
- NAME

And another one called RECIPE_INGREDIENTS

- RECIPE_ID
- INGREDIENT_ID

Then for your example of bread and butter, in RECIPE:

```
ID | Name
-----------------
1  | Sandwich
```

And in ingredients

```
RECIPE_ID | INGREDIENT_ID
1         | 2
1         | 3
```

For something made up of Bread and Milk

```
ID | Name
-----------------
2  | Milky Bread
```

And

```
RECIPE_ID | INGREDIENT_ID
2         | 1
2         | 2
```

Comment: so i should create 'dumb' table with connections? equivalent to RECIPE table?

Comment: @Qiao - in my example the dumb table is actually the one named "RECIPIE_INGREDIENTS".  That is what creates the connection that tells you which ingredients are connected to each other for each connection.  Since Butter has two connections, one to bread and one to milk, I felt it appropriate to add an identifier to each of these distinct connections - in this instance I used the metaphor of a recipe to identify them.  I created the RECIPE table, rather than habing a third column in the connections table, so that (as Bill Karwin pointed out) it was in first normal form.